# compiler optimisations and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program that performs a task in a thread and I wanted to have the option to terminate early with a key-press. Here is a MWE:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char endChar = 0;// endChar is only written by keyboard thread
  std::thread kbth([&endChar]() { std::cin >> endChar; });//this thread monitors the keyboard
  kbth.detach();

  std::chrono::seconds run_t{15};
  bool running = true; // running could be written by main and task thread at
                       // same time (unlikely)
  std::mutex task_mtx; // so protect with mutex
  std::thread task([&running, &run_t, &task_mtx]() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(run_t);
    std::scoped_lock lock{task_mtx};
    running = false;
  });                                                   //this thread performs the task
  task.detach();

  while (running) {                                     //running is false when the task ends
    if (endChar == 42) { // 42=*
      std::cout << "key pressed" << std::endl;
      std::scoped_lock lock{task_mtx};
      running = false;                                  //or when * is entered 
      break;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
}
```

This works fine without compiler optimisations but fails with optimisations. Please can someone help me understand why this is happening? According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) compilers can optimise code as long as they don't change "the observable behavior of the program". So when this fails when optimisations are on doesn't this count as changing the observable behaviour? I tried with g++ and cl, summarised:

```
// clang-format off
// g++ version 11.2.1 fedora 64bit
// g++ -O0 -std=c++1z ../src/kbthread.cpp -o kbthread -l pthread //OK, exits gracefully when done or when key pressed 
// g++ -O1 -std=c++1z ../src/kbthread.cpp -o kbthread -l pthread //fail, hang 
// g++ -O2 -std=c++1z ../src/kbthread.cpp -o kbthread -l pthread //fail, hang

// cl version 19.29.30133 for x64 windows
// cl /EHsc -std:c++17 -Od -MD ../src/kbthread.cpp //OK, exits gracefully when done or when key pressed 
// cl /EHsc -std:c++17 -O1 -MD ../src/kbthread.cpp // fail, immediately prints "key pressed\nbye" 
// cl /EHsc -std:c++17 -O2 -MD ../src/kbthread.cpp // fail, immediately prints "key pressed\nbye"
// clang-format on
```

Comment: You can't have multiple threads access the same object, unless those accesses are all reads. As soon as one thread can write to it, you have Undefined Behavior, the compiler can do absolutely anything it wants. You need to synchronize those objects so that only 1 thread can access them at once (see `std::mutex`) or use thread-safe wrapper (see `std::atomic`). Additionally, you will often introduce similar problems when using `detach()`, using the function is almost always an error.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `if (endChar == 42) { // 42=*` should be written `if (endChar == '*') {`.

Comment: When you say `fails` what does that mean? Crashes? Produces an unexpected result? As you've detached your threads there is a good chance that one or more of them will still be running after the end of `main` this means that if they try to write to the variables declared in `main` you have undefined behaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtles The block at the end of the question has comments indicating the type of failure. You may have to scroll the section as the lines are quite long.

Comment: `endChar` and `running` are shared variables. There should be a mutual exclusion among the threads that access them. Beside `std::mutex`, you can look into `std::unique_lock`. You may find this useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwJ4Eh_2Umo

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux this should be an answer.

Comment: So I checked to see if the thread access to shared variable "running" could be the issue and it doesn't seem to be. This is the only variable that could be written by two threads at the same time, but unlikely -- key press would have to be made at same moment the task was finishing. Not sure how to check the detach() issue. The placement of join() is not clear. I understand that join() blocks at that point to wait for the thread. So if I put a task.join() after the while then the key press would not end the program early.

Comment: You're conflating "access" with "writing" but it means "read or write". If one thread writes a variable while another reads it, those are both accesses, and they both need to be either `atomic` or protected by a mutex.

Comment: @stegzzz It doesn't matter if you observe the race or not. The compiler is allowed to make the assumption that you don't break any rules. Since `endChar` is initialized to 0 and the compiler doesn't see anything synchronizing it, it can assume it is never changed. It is then allowed to change the loop condition from `endChar == 42` to just `false` since, from that perspective, the condition will never change. The fact that there *could* be a simultaneous read and write can on its own break your program, regardless of if this ever actually happens.

Comment: To help understand why this is happening, you can have a read of std::memory_order https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order which discusses the rules of how memory access can be optimized by the compiler, although it's a reasonably complicated topic. Related (and slightly simpler) is volatile, but not appropriate for inter thread communication https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question. Post it as answer instead. I rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as comments below indicated threading issues @ François Andrieux I have "fixed" it using atomics with the code below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::atomic_char endChar{0};
  std::thread kbth([&endChar]() { // this thread monitors the keyboard
    char buff = 0;
    std::cin >> buff;
    endChar = buff;
  });
  kbth.detach();

  std::chrono::seconds run_t{10};
  std::atomic_bool running{true};
  std::thread task([&running, &run_t]() { // this thread performs the task
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(run_t);
    running = false;
  });
  task.detach();

  while (running.load()) { // running is false when the task ends, so the program ends
    if (endChar.load() == 42) { // 42=*
      std::cout << "key pressed" << std::endl;
      running = false;     // or when * is entered, so the program ends early
      break;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
}
```

Still not sure about the use of detach but seems to work OK now.