# prevent compiler optimisation for looped volatile variable check in thread

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, volatile

Below code prints less "end" than "start" and I believe it's due to `pAStruct->valueInMemory` getting optimised away; because when I quit the application "quit" is printed.

When I surround the `while` by `printf` the application performs as expected, although the `while` is untouched.

```c
typedef AStruct {
    volatile int valueInMemory;
} aStruct;

volatile int quit = 0;      // indicator to quit application


// ... snip


unsigned __stdcall myThread(void* data) {
    printf("start");
    aStruct* pAStruct = (aStruct*)data;
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; ++i) {
        // following code excerpt is the only other loop:
        while (pAStruct->valueInMemory) {
                            // valueInMemory is written as 0 from another thread
            if (quit)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("end");
    return 0;
}


// ... snip


aStruct aS;
aS.valueInMemory = 1;

HANDLE hMyThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, myThread, (void*)&aS, 0, NULL);

while(!quit) {
    int m = poll();         // *abstracted* from actual message code

    if(m == QUIT_MESSAGE) {
        quit = 1;
    }
}

WaitForSingleObject(hMyThread, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(hMyThread);

printf("quit");
```

Note:

[What happens if two threads read & write the same piece of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580291/what-happens-if-two-threads-read-write-the-same-piece-of-memory) indicates reading is "undefined" but a single wrong concurrent read does not matter here. I appear to require the read in the first place.

[compiler optimisations and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855685/compiler-optimisations-and-threads) fixes it by using atomics but https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-atomics-in-visual-studio-2022-version-17-5-preview-2/ `_Atomic` (where I use volatile) did not help (despite the syntax highlighter indicating invalid type specifier it did compile and run) (would I have to do more than add `_Atomic`?)

I seek a solution which does not involve a performance delay (so should be < 1ms on "todays PCs") similar to indicated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174159/5588495 (but I didn't grasp that in the time I spent)

Comment: oh, it's not that, I omitted the `\n` for brevitys sake. "end" is printed, but not sufficiently often. This demo is an excerpt from a larger app running several `myThread` some of whose `for` don't enter the case where there is the `while`

Comment: This code can't print `"quit"` and there is nothing that sets `valueInMemory` to 0. Consider putting together a [mcve] that demonstrates the full picture.

Comment: Are you compiling with `/volatile:ms` (either by default or explicitly)?  If not, `int quit` is not `volatile` so without any kind of acquire / release semantics a load from it can get hoisted out of loops, even if there's a volatile read in the loop.  Also, `while(!quit) { ... }` is fully broken, unless the non-inline function call happens to get the compiler to reload it.  (Probably the same thing you're seeing in the other loop.)  [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/387181)

Comment: If your syntax highlighter doesn't know about `_Atomic`, it's probably assuming C++ pre C++23.  Just make `quit` itself `_Atomic bool`, and check it with `memory_order_relaxed` occasionally.  Or `atomic_load_explicit(&quit, memory_order_acquire)` if you want some synchronization with the writer.  See [Why set the stop flag using \`memory\_order\_seq\_cst\`, if you check it with \`memory\_order\_relaxed\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70581645) which also discusses inter-thread latency that you're concerned about.  It'll be sub-microsecond.  `_Atomic` stopes the compiler from optimizing away th

Comment: i run the app ~50 more times in the past 24 hours and once it run as expected. Thus the `_Atomic` variable inside the `while` condition wasn't optimised away. I investigated further by adding a `printf` to after that variable was set to 0 from the other thread and this always occured in further tests but the loop didn't end (no "end" printed) in all cases. I wonder whether the polling is too fast and the `_Atomic` variable didn't receive 0 after all or it was cached but I didn't find cues on the web this might occur. AMD64 PC. I currently solve this by `Sleep(1)` inside the `while`.

Comment: I leave this question open for possible replies about all scenarios which might occur (`volatile` in non-threaded context, `_Atomic` in threaded context with newer compilers, cache considerations or concurrency alternatives (in C))

Comment: *Below code prints less "end" than "start"* - I don't see how it would *ever* print `end`.  `while (pAStruct->valueInMemory)` is always true because it was set to `1` before starting the thread.  So you spin in that loop until `if (quit)` becomes true on some iteration, and leave the thread via `if (quit) return 0;`, not the `for(int i=0` loop reaching max iterations, unless `SIZE` is 0 or lower.

Comment: Oh, there's a comment about `valueInMemory` being written as `0` from another thread, but how is that ordered wrt. writing `quit`?  If the store to `quit` is visible first, the thread can leave via `if(quit) return 0;` instead of falling out of the `for` loop.  Even if the `quit=1` is visible second, **both** `valueInMemory=0` and `quit=1` could become visible to your thread between its check of `valueInMemory` and its check of `quit`.  There isn't another check of `valueInMemory` after seeing `quit != 0` to catch the case where they both changed.

Comment: the `quit` is no issue, it's to end the thread prematurely when the user instructed the app to quit during a thread waiting (and during debugging it tells me the app is actually responding when i click quit). This is only a snippet of the whole code. I'm interested in  reaching the `end` where i do further processing in the real code; the example above is boiled down to where I think I identified the issue to be: the variable in the `while` condition. First I thought it was optimised out as 1 by the compiler and I seeked solutions to prevent this here but now this is not the case see comment 5

Comment: *prevent compiler optimisation...*  That's a huge red flag indicating buggy code IMO.  If your code only works when you prevent compiler optimizations, unless there's a compiler bug (**not** likely...), that means your code depends on undefined behavior to do what you want.  Which means you can **never** rely on it doing what you want.  The best you will ever do is get to the point where you don't observe any failures, but you have no guarantee the next time you compile your code it won't fail.  Or maybe it fails on the next loop iteration...